# unix command formatting flattening nested json objects data

Tags: command-line, text-formatting, json

example input data format json

```
data: {
   div1: {
      name: "some name",
      age: number,
      address_1: "some address",
      items: {
         item_x1: "some data",
         ..
         ..
      }
   }
   ..
   ..
}
```

expected result should be formatted flatten json

```
{ "data.div1.name":"some name",..., "data.div1.items.item_x1":"some data",...},
..
..
{ "data.divN.name":"some name",... }
```

fields can be unknown! so there is not necessary to activate any filtration command!

any ideas for unix based command ?

Comment: to be a valid JSON `data` should be an object key --> `{'data:' {...}}`. Post a valid JSON

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at [gron](https://github.com/tomnomnom/gron). From the linked page:

> Make JSON greppable!
>
> `gron` transforms JSON into discrete assignments to make it easier to grep for what you want and see the absolute 'path' to it. It eases the exploration of APIs that return large blobs of JSON but have terrible documentation.

```
▶ gron "https://api.github.com/repos/tomnomnom/gron/commits?per_page=1" | fgrep "commit.author"
json[0].commit.author = {};
json[0].commit.author.date = "2016-07-02T10:51:21Z";
json[0].commit.author.email = "mail@tomnomnom.com";
json[0].commit.author.name = "Tom Hudson";
```

> gron can work backwards too, enabling you to turn your filtered data back into JSON:

```
▶ gron "https://api.github.com/repos/tomnomnom/gron/commits?per_page=1" | fgrep "commit.author" | gron --ungron
[
  {
    "commit": {
      "author": {
        "date": "2016-07-02T10:51:21Z",
        "email": "mail@tomnomnom.com",
        "name": "Tom Hudson"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

**`Jq`** is the right tool for processing JSON data (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/).

Sample `input.json`:

```
{
  "data": {
    "div1": {
      "name": "some name",
      "age": 1,
      "address_1": "some address",
      "items": {
        "item_x1": "some data"
      }
    },
    "div2": {
      "name": "some other name",
      "age": 2,
      "address_2": "some address",
      "items": {
        "item_x2": "some data"
      }
    },
    "div3": {
      "name": "another name",
      "age": 3,
      "address_3": "some address",
      "items": {
        "item_x3": "some data"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
jq -c '"data" as $main_k | .data as $data | .data | to_entries
       | group_by(.key) | map(from_entries)[] | [paths(scalars)]
       | map(("\($main_k)." + join(".")) as $key
             | {($key): (reduce .[] as $k ($data; . = .[$k]))})
       | add' input.json
```

The output:

```
{"data.div1.name":"some name","data.div1.age":1,"data.div1.address_1":"some address","data.div1.items.item_x1":"some data"}
{"data.div2.name":"some other name","data.div2.age":2,"data.div2.address_2":"some address","data.div2.items.item_x2":"some data"}
{"data.div3.name":"another name","data.div3.age":3,"data.div3.address_3":"some address","data.div3.items.item_x3":"some data"}
```

Comment: very nice. do we have to use escape here --> `\($main_k)` ?

Comment: @mr.tee, yes, we do